# What message triggers can be found in the dedupe process?

Tags: email, duplicate-contacts

We a deduping a lot of records, many of which were imported from sources prior to using CiviCRM. Apparently, at least one merged record triggered a change of email notification. Can I kill those notifications? There are likely to be many of them.

Is there a specific trigger? For example, if we overwrite a record with an old address with a new address instead of opting to keep just the newer record? The point is that we don't want to send a pile of notices for changed email addresses.

Comment: I have never heard of a "change of email notification". so you are saying if my contact records has the email changed, then a notification is sent to my old (or new) email saying it has been updated? do you maybe have an extension or is this just part of civicrm i haven't stumbled upon yet

Comment: This sounds like something that eg CiviRules or Drupal Rules might do.

Comment: I think that's a wordpress thing isn't it? Pick some unique text out of the email and do a grep for it in both civi and wordpress and extensions - that should help locate it, unless it is a Rules config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it this wordpress feature?
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202783/fwd-website-name-notice-of-email-change

https://build.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/wp-includes/user.php#L2056

Short answer to prevent it: `add_filter( 'send_email_change_email', '__return_false' );`

Any time a contact record is updated, civi will attempt to update the corresponding user account in the CMS for name and email. So it would only be for contacts that have an associated user account.

You can also turn this sync off at Administer - System Settings - CMS Database Integration - Sync CMS Email, but then your users and contact records can get out of sync.

Comment: So,  I'm guessing that this gets triggered if the WordPress user email gets updated in a sync with Civi?

Comment: I'll add some more info to the answer.